# Is the HST going to affect college or university tuition fees? Can I pay early to avoid it?

Tags: canada, hst, tuition

I have been looking and can't find any info on whether HST is applied to college / university tuition. If so, can I pay by the end of June to avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

University tuition and textbooks will remain **unaffected by the HST** being introduced in both Ontario and British Columbia on July 1st.

In Ontario, refer to the Ministry of Revenue's page [Tax Benefits for Students](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/taxchange/students.html).  Excerpt:

> **Rebates and Exemptions**
>
> The HST will not be charged on the
>   following items, commonly used by
>   students, that are currently not
>   subject to PST, including:
>
> - **Tutoring and Tuition Fees**
> - Residential rents
> - Basic groceries
> - Municipal public transit
>     *[etc...]*